# Is there a way to get console.table to execute property accessor functions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have a collection of objects with many getter properties. I'd like to be able to print a subset of these values in the console using `console.table`. The current implementations do not seem to allow this, is there a workaround?

```
let obj = {
    get prop() {
        return "getter";
    }
    id:1
}

console.table([obj]); // prints only index, and id
console.table([obj], ["prop"]); // prints only index, but still not "prop"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `console.table` api is [still non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table).

Currently - chrome is not capable of working with [getters values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), and if you will check firefox - all values that are defined by getters are printed as `undefined`.

Note that this has nothing to do with `hasOwnProperty` or `'prop' in obj` (both works great), however it might be related to `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

In your example (for both Chrome & Firefox):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'id').value
// 1
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'prop').value
// undefined
```

However if this is the case I would expect from Chrome to also display the `prop` column (even with the undefined values in it).

You can use this snippet to test on your browser:

```js
let obj = {
    get prop() {
        return "getter";
    },
    id:1
}

console.log('Log "t in obj"')
for (var t in obj) {
  console.log(t, obj[t]);
}
console.log('')

console.table([obj]);
console.table([obj], ["id"]);
console.table([obj], ["prop"]); // currently returns a column of 'undefined' in firefox, and in chrome that column doesn't exists.
```